# Command failed docker-compose in VScode Devcontainer

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, vscode-devcontainer

I've just started using Docker on an already existing project (it runs into a Docker container). I don't have a lot of Docker background - I've been using it only from the GUI, by pressing the "play" button.

Now I have a project which runs into a container, and I'm having trouble starting it.

I'm getting this error:

```
[2022-03-31T15:30:27.408Z] Error: Command failed: docker-compose -f c:\Users\Octavian\Desktop\django-analyzer\docker-compose.dev.yml config
[2022-03-31T15:30:27.408Z]     at Ru (c:\Users\Octavian\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.231.1\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:209:813)
[2022-03-31T15:30:27.408Z]     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
[2022-03-31T15:30:27.408Z]     at async dR (c:\Users\Octavian\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.231.1\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:181:643)
[2022-03-31T15:30:27.408Z]     at async hR (c:\Users\Octavian\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.231.1\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:178:2075)
[2022-03-31T15:30:27.408Z]     at async RR (c:\Users\Octavian\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.231.1\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:223:2195)
[2022-03-31T15:30:27.408Z]     at async Jw (c:\Users\Octavian\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.231.1\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:223:3221)
[2022-03-31T15:30:27.409Z]     at async TR (c:\Users\Octavian\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.231.1\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:223:13880)
[2022-03-31T15:30:27.409Z]     at async FR (c:\Users\Octavian\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.231.1\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:223:13605)
[2022-03-31T15:30:27.417Z] Stop (3507 ms): Run: C:\Users\Octavian\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe c:\Users\Octavian\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.231.1\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js up --container-data-folder .vscode-server/data/Machine --container-system-data-folder /var/vscode-server --workspace-folder c:\Users\Octavian\Desktop\django-analyzer --workspace-mount-consistency cached --id-label vsch.local.folder=c:\Users\Octavian\Desktop\django-analyzer --id-label vsch.quality=stable --log-level debug --config c:\Users\Octavian\Desktop\django-analyzer\.devcontainer\devcontainer.json --mount type=volume,source=vscode,target=/vscode,external=true --skip-post-create --update-remote-user-uid-default on --mount-workspace-git-root true
[2022-03-31T15:30:27.417Z] Exit code 1
[2022-03-31T15:30:27.420Z] Command failed: C:\Users\Octavian\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe c:\Users\Octavian\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.231.1\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js up --container-data-folder .vscode-server/data/Machine --container-system-data-folder /var/vscode-server --workspace-folder c:\Users\Octavian\Desktop\django-analyzer --workspace-mount-consistency cached --id-label vsch.local.folder=c:\Users\Octavian\Desktop\django-analyzer --id-label vsch.quality=stable --log-level debug --config c:\Users\Octavian\Desktop\django-analyzer\.devcontainer\devcontainer.json --mount type=volume,source=vscode,target=/vscode,external=true --skip-post-create --update-remote-user-uid-default on --mount-workspace-git-root true
[2022-03-31T15:30:27.421Z] Exit code 1
```

Here's my docker-compose.yml (if it helps)

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  redis:
    //data

  postgres:
    //data

  django:
    //data

volumes:
  db-data:
```

Where can this error come from and how can I fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

It looks like you're trying to VS Code devcontainers. The error output is not super helpful here.

docker-compose seems to not like the format of your docker-compose.dev.yml file because it errors out on:

```sh
docker-compose -f c:\Users\Octavian\Desktop\django-analyzer\docker-compose.dev.yml config
```

Try running that command at your command line and it should give you better info on why your docker-compose.dev.yml is invalid.

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into this problem myself and the issue was that my compose file wasn't compatible with the V1 compose command-line. Going into the Docker Desktop general preferences and enabling "Use Docker Compose V2" fixed it.

Comment: I already had that i.e. doesn't work for me!

Comment: In my case, it was already enabled. Disabling it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try to check your docker version. then select the appropriate compactibility version from [HERE](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/) then try this for official [HERE](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/) or you can try this one for template compose file [HERE](https://www.encora.com/insights/docker-compose-v3-production-ready)

Make sure your docker is propery installed on your local machine.

Comment: My docker compose uses 3.7, which according to your link supports Docker Engine   18.06.0+. After running a docker --version in my terminal, I get Docker version 20.10.10, build b485636. So, they should be compatible I guess.